# How to query a specific item from a specific List in a one-to-many relationship

Tags: swift, realm

Based on the code blow, how can I query the item with name `Grapes` from `List 2`?

I know how to get all items from `List 2` but what I want is to get only the item with name `Grapes` from `List 2`

```
 let itemsFromList2 = realm.objects(ShoppingList.self).filter("listName = 'List 2' ").first?.itemList
```

## CODE

**ShoppingLists Model**

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class ShoppingList: Object{
    dynamic var listName = ""
    var itemList = List<Item>()
}
```

**Item Model**

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Item:Object {
    dynamic var productName: String = ""
}
```

**Output of all ShoppingLists ( *realm.objects(ShoppingList.self)* )**

```
Lists: Results<ShoppingList> (
    [0] ShoppingList {
        listName = List 1;
        itemList = RLMArray <0x6180000feb80> (
            [0] Item {
                productName = Tomatoes;
            },
            [1] Item {
                productName = Grapes;
            },
            [2] Item {
                productName = Oranges;
            }
        );
    },
    [1] ShoppingList {
        listName = List 2;
        itemList = RLMArray <0x6180000fec80> (
            [0] Item {
                productName = Tomatoes;
            },
            [1] Item {
                productName = Grapes;
            },
            [2] Item {
                productName = Oranges;
            },
            [3] Item {
                productName = Green Peppers;
            },
            [4] Item {
                productName = Apples;
            }
        );
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain together multiple Realm filters and hence directly filter the `itemList` property of `List 2`. Realm filters work on `List` as well, not just `Results`.

```
let itemsFromList2 = realm.objects(ShoppingList.self).filter("listName = 'List 2' ").first?.itemList.filter("productName == 'Grapes'")
```

You use variable names inside `NSPredicate`s using the `%@` syntax:

```
let itemsFromList2 = realm.objects(ShoppingList.self).filter("listName = 'List 2' ").first?.itemList.filter("productName == %@", myFruit)
```

Comment: Pasztor - Quick question: what if 'Grapes' need to be dynamic?`let itemsFromList2 = realm.objects(ShoppingList.self).filter("listName = 'List 2' ").first?.itemList.filter("productName == muFruit")`  where myFruit is a String variable.

Comment: You just use `filter("productName == %@", myFruit)`, see my updated answer. Same principle goes for the list name as well if you want to make that dynamic.